# How's the Control flow skips outer function call when we run inner function call as it go Top to Bottom of whole code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all the program run Outer function call and print the message then the program run **Inner function call** inside a conditional block of **While loop** when we put **“Yes”** in input but as you aware when we do that **Control flow** goes to **Top** of the whole code at the run process. My question is how the Control flow **skips** over **outer function call** if it go **Top** to **Bottom**?

```
def start_code():
    print "Hello Earthian"

start_code()

while True:
    repeat_input = raw_input("Do you want to repeat?")
    if repeat_input == "Yes" or repeat_input == "yes":
        start_code()
    elif repeat_input == "No" or repeat_input == "no":
        print "-------------------------------------------\nGood Bye!\n-------------------------------------------"
        break
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, I could not understand. Please say either Yes or No"
```

Comment: Keep going. You didn't *reach* the second `start_code` call - or rather, you didn't reach the `print` in the second call.

Comment: Could you add the code to the question body?

Comment: Please share the code, not a link to some website which might or might be still around tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is written in the code twice, but that doesn't mean the function will always be called twice. The second call to `start_code()` is never executed because it's part of a *conditional block* that isn't activated. Take the following snippet:

```
repeat_input = raw_input("Do you want to repeat?")
if repeat_input == "Yes" or repeat_input == "yes":
    start_code()
elif repeat_input == "No" or repeat_input == "no":
    print "..."
    break
else:
    print "I'm sorry, I could not understand. Please say either Yes or No"
```

First, the program asks the user to input something, and saves whatever they input to `repeat_input`. Then, there are three statements at the same level of indentation: `if`, `elif`, and `else`. These are called *conditionals*, and any code inside each conditional is only run if the conditions are met (see the difference in indentation? that's what I mean by "inside" - the second call to `start_code()` is *inside* the `if`).

The first of these statements checks if `repeat_input` - the variable holding the text the user entered - is equal to `"Yes"` or `"yes"`. If it is, then it runs everything inside that block, which in this case is just the function `start_code`.

The second of these statements is `elif`, which stands for "else if". This line is only ever executed if the `if` statement before it was *not* activated - in which case it checks whether `repeat_input` is equal to `"No"` or `"no"`. If that's the case, then it runs the code inside the `elif` block - the `print` statement and the `break` statement.

The third of these statements is `else` - if all of the preceding `if` and `elif` statements are not activated, then the code inside this block is run - the next `print` statement.

These three statements - `if`, `elif`, and `else` - come as a unit. You must have one `if` statement, can have any number of `elif` statements, and can have up to one `else` statement at the end. After any one of them is activated, and the code inside that one is run, the program jumps to *after* the block inside the `else` statement - in this case, that means going to the next iteration of the `while` loop that's enclosing the entire thing.

---

So, in summary, the second call to `start_code()` is only run if the user types `"Yes"` or `"yes"` when prompted by the program.

Comment: @GreenClockGuy I know this because i created whole code. My question is why it skips first function call in outside of conditional block when it calls the second function inside the conditional block? I provided a visual link to visualise but it Jumps like a frog (skip) the first function in body.

Comment: It doesn't skip the first function call. If you look closely at step 4 of the visualization, that's when it calls the function the first time. Then, step 10, it calls the function the second time. In both cases, the line marker jumps up to the place where you defined the function, and runs through the function. Keep in mind it *only runs through the function* - which is everything indented under the `def start_code():` line. The first call to `start_code()` is at the same level of indentation as `def start_code():`, which means that it's not *inside* the function.

Comment: Whenever you call `start_code()`, the python interpreter jumps to the function, executes everything inside of it, then jumps back to where it was. It doesn't pay attention to anything in between.

Comment: @GreenClockGuy I just edited the whole question to provide a more clear view about my question.

Comment: @GreenCoakGuy  How come it does not pay attention to anything in between but restart the while loop?

Comment: If it does not pay attention to anything in between then it should not restart while loop but this one does restart while loop.

Comment: It doesn't pay attention to the `while` loop because it's between the call and the function - it pays attention to the `while` loop because, after the second `start_code()` is executed, the python interpreter jumps back to it, goes to the next line - which is at the end of the `if`/`elif`/`else` block - and finds that it's at the end of the `while` loop, but *still inside the `while` loop*. So it checks whether to make another loop (`True == True`, so yes) and *jumps back up to the start of the `while` loop. [Here's an attempt at visualizing, with arrows](https://i.imgur.com/6qBXNkb.png)